# Angular2: Open ngbPopover containing image delayed on hover

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

First of all: I created a plunkr to show the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/5IhhqtofCvqqr5x9P0De?p=preview

I want to open a ngbPopover (with image) delayed on hovering an element.
I use `(mouseover)` and `(mouseleave)` in combination with `triggers="manual"`. Inside the opening function i use `setTimeout` which triggers the popover opening. Everything works fine but not on the first execution. As you can see on the picture the popover is placed wrongly.

[image: problem showcase]

On the second, third, ... hover everything works fine. When i remove the timeout function it works, too, but that's not my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is a tricky one! Before I suggest a work-around (as I'm not sure there is a way of "fixing" it), let me explain what is going on here.

In order to position elements properly we need to know **exact size** of an element to be positioned. In your particular case the exact size is only known *after* a browser loaded an image.

There are 2 basic ways of working-around the issue:

- re-position popover *after* image has been loaded
- give image a size upfront.

The problem with re-positioning popover *after image load* is that you would have to listen to `<img>`'s `onload` event and then force re-positioning. This is cumbersome and today's implementation of ng-bootstrap popover doesn't have any method of forcing re-positioning (although we could easily add one!).

What I would suggest instead is to give the `<img>` element initial size so when we position things the exact dimensions are known before image loads. Ex. `width="200px" height="140px"` like so:

```
<ng-template #popContent let-greeting="greeting">
 <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Crested_Tern_Tasmania_%28edit%29.jpg/1600px-Crested_Tern_Tasmania_%28edit%29.jpg" 
width="200px"
height="140px">
</ng-template>
```

With the fixed dimensions of an image things start to work as expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/QUxBX1KCPVaAkIfBH0P8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

try use this property 
its is simplest and cleanest solution. 
Basically, default value for trigger is click. 
but is you just can change that property to 
**triggers="hover"**
it will help you up